# How to jump line on android

Tags: java, android

I'm develop an android app but I don't know how to jump line or more while set the text of text view so how can I do this ?
On html I use \n but I don't know How to do it from java
Like this
Android
A
n
d
r
o
i
d
(Every space meanning new line)
Note that this text will appear on text view

Comment: Did you try to put `"1st line\n2nd line"` as the text of the `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

Before using \n, you must set the `android:maxLines` attribute in XML. For example, in XML for the above text, you could say:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:maxLines = "7"
    android:text = "A\nn\nd\nr\no\ni\nd"    
/>
```

Or if you wanted to do it from Java, you could do:

```
textView.setMaxLines(7);
textView.setText("A\nn\nd\nr\no\ni\nd");
```